# How do you transfer azure subscription

Tags: azure, subscription

Microsoft has documentation on how to transfer a subscription here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer
and here

https://ea.azure.com/helpdocs/changeAccountOwnerForASubscription

In the documentation, they show a button to transfer a subscription at https://account.azure.com
[image]

However when I go to account.azure.com and create a subscription, I do not have the ability to transfer a subscription, even though I just created it.

[image]

I am using a Microsoft Azure Enterprise agreement, (not a "pay as you go" payment)

How can I transfer a subscription?

Comment: Product licensing inquiries are [expressly off topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) at Server Fault.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because billing and licensing questions should be asked of the vendor.

Comment: I disagree with these comments and the decision to close this question as off-topic. This is not a licensing / billing inquiry of the vendor. This is a "how do I use a COTS software management GUI to achieve a specific technical configuration". At present there is no specific home for cloud / virtualization Q&A in the Stack Exchange space and we need that. Until such a home is created, we need to use existing exchanges such as Server Fault, Super User and Stack Overflow. MODERATORS: Plus do not shut down users who are simply trying to use the tools available to get help.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that enterprise agrements have a slightly different method for changing the owner. It is documented at the very bottom of this link.

https://ea.azure.com/helpdocs/changeAccountOwnerForASubscription

1. login into ea.azure.com portal
2. Select Manage
3. Select Account
4. Click the icon on the right most side of the subscription where to want to move the subscription to/from (not available on all subscriptions, [e.g you can't move from a 'work' account to a 'personal' account. )

[image]
[image]